How can I use feasibility method to get my call logs?
I have write a method to realize my expection, but it doesn't work.

Permission Request and Handling

Problem: The code checks for permissions but does not handle the user’s response to the permission request properly. Additionally, there might be a typo in the permission string for READ_PHONE_STATE.

Solution: Ensure that permission strings are correct and handle the permission request result. You should also consider using the plus.android.Permission helper class for a more streamlined experience.
getCallLogs() {                            //获取通话记录                try {                   const main=plus.android.runtimeMainActivity();                  const PackageManager=plus.android.importClass("android.content.pm.PackageManager");                                         //检查是否有READ_CALL_LOG权限                  const HasCallLogPermission=main.checkSelfPermission("android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG")===PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;                    //检查是否有Read_PHONE_STATE权限                   const HasStatePermission=main.checkSelfPermission("android.permission.Read_PHONE_STATE")===PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;                                                           if(!HasCallLogPermission || !HasStatePermission){                       //请求获取READ_CALL_LOG权限                       main.requestPermission(["android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"],0);                       //请求获取                  }                                         // 获取 Android 系统的 ContentResolver 类和 CallLog.Calls 类                    const ContentResolver = plus.android.importClass("android.content.ContentResolver");                    const Uri = plus.android.importClass("android.net.Uri");                    const Cursor = plus.android.importClass("android.database.Cursor");                     const CallLog = plus.android.importClass("android.provider.CallLog");                                           // // 获取当前活动的 Activity 对象                       // const main = plus.android.runtimeMainActivity();                                         // 获取 ContentResolver 对象                    const contentResolver = main.getContentResolver();                      plus.android.importClass(contentResolver);                                      // 定义通话记录 URI                       const callLogUri = CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI;                                           // 查询通话记录                       const cursor = contentResolver.query(callLogUri, null, null, null, CallLog.Calls.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);                       plus.android.importClass(cursor);                                       // 存储通话记录的数组                    const callLogs = [];                                      // 遍历 Cursor 并获取通话记录                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {                         const number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));                       const date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE));                       const duration = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION));                       const type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE));                                       // 添加到 callLogs 数组                      callLogs.push({                           number,                         date,                           duration                      });                       }                                       // 关闭 Cursor                    cursor.close();                                     // 处理通话记录                       console.log('通话记录:', callLogs);                     // 你可以将 callLogs 数据绑定到 Vue 组件的 data 或其他处理逻辑中                                  } catch (error) {                     console.error('获取通话记录失败', error);                       throw new Error('获取通话记录失败，请检查权限和设备设置');                   }                                           },




point out the problem and provide feasible solutions.
